# Is this a good OO design?

Tags: oop, architecture, skeletal-animation

I'm building an API for myself to do 2D skeletal animation.

I have a Bone class
and a Skeleton class.

The Skeleton creates a root bone and then subsequent bones are added via the Skeleton's add method by providing the parent bone.

What I now want to do is add animation and frames.

What I was thinking of, is a class that can load and interpolate animations. So it would be an object that would load an animation. It would then, at each frame, take in a Skeleton and modify the Skeleton accordingly.

Is this a good design? Should an animation take in a Skeleton, or should a Skeleton take in an animation and apply it onto itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's best to create an Animation that makes use of a Skeleton instead of the opposite. This because, logically speaking, the object Skeleton does not require an Animation to live, but an Animation strongly requires a Skeleton.
So you can couple those elements in the Animation itself. Do not put too much logics in the objects, and try to put it just where necessary.

Comment: I see, so I should base it on dependencies. Thanks!

Comment: Well, the best implementation has the less possible coupling between objects, I think. So you should try to link them just where necessary and not everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably every bone has a 2d position/angle and an animation is a collection of frames where each frame is a collection of bone identifiers and position/angles?

Then you might consider something like

```
public class Skeleton
{
    public List<Bone> Bones {get;set;}
    public void Animate(Animation animation)
    {
        foreach(Bone bone in Bones)
        {
           bone.Displace(animation.Displacements.FirstOrDefault(o=>o.BoneId == bone.BoneID));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create an `Animation` class containing a `std::vector<Skeleton>` data member that you can use to manipulate individual `Skeleton` objects on each frame or interpolate across multiple `Skeleton` objects in the vector from keyframes.  Then when you "play" the animation, you merely have to iterate over the vector, calling out each `Skeleton` object, and pass that to some other function or class that will display the results on-screen (or do whatever else the `Skeleton` can be useful for, such as warping a mesh, etc.)

Having an animation object will make it much easier to manipulate the frames of the animation, allowing you to remove/replace frames, etc.  Otherwise if you try to pile all of this functionality into a Skeleton object, then you're going to find there's a lot of baggage when trying to manipulate individual aspects of the Skeleton separately from the animation sequence (i.e. suppose you need to change the hierarchy of the Skeleton for a segment of frames, etc.? ... that would be very easy if there is a Skeleton on each frame, but not if you have a monolithic Skelton object).